# Two-variable ODEs with one variable fixed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

How do you solve variables with $f(x,y)$ where we only take the derivative wrt one of the variables? I presume the other variable can be taken as fixed, but I don't know what changes we need to make to our usual formulas?

e.g. $$f_x(x,y) + f(x,y) = 1$$

Also, how would you use Maple to solve them? If I define an $ode$ and use dsolve, it says "required specification of the indeterminate function".

Comment: If you only take the derivative with respect to one variable, you can solve it as an ODE. Here, use an integrating factor $e^{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

In maple, you are suppose to use `pdsolve` to solve a pde not `dsolve`,

```
restart;
Eq1:= diff(f(x,y),x)+f(x,y)=1;
pdsolve(Eq1);
```

[image]